# "Could not write feature into OUTPUT" error when running "Shortest path (point to layer)" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-processing, error, shortest-path

I use QGIS 3.26 with a point and a line layer, representing cities connected by a network. Running QGIS native tool ["Shortest path (point to layer)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#shortest-path-point-to-layer), I get the following error message:

```
Feature could not be written to
Shortest_path_9e8035ba_f9d3_4f72_a757_79b2f7744abb: 
Could not store attribute "cost": 
Could not convert value "4696680.63606, 4486744.97588" to target type
Could not write feature into OUTPUT
```

What does this error message mean and how can the problem be solved?

The two layers were exported as KMZ files from [Gephi, The Open Graph Viz Platform](https://gephi.org/) and converted from KMZ to GeoPackage files in QGIS by exporting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is connected with the attribute in the point layer: by exporting from Gephi to KMZ, it contains several fields with empty values (`NULL`), between else a field `"begin"` and a field `"end"`.

The "Shortest path (point to layer)" tool, however, creates three attribute fields called `"start"`, `"end"` and `"cost"`. As there already exists a field called `"end"`, the error occurs. Deleting the field `"end"` with its `NULL` values in the point layer, the error disappears, and "Shortest path (point to layer)" runs like a charm.